# How to center text vertically within bootstrap container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center text vertically within a div bootstrap container. This is my sample HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
.vcenter {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 float:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default vcenter ">

    <ul class="list-inline vcenter" >
   <li class="menuFont"><a href="/">Menu 1</a></li>
   <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 2</a></li>
   <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 3</a></li>
   <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 4</a></li>
   <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 5</a></li>
   <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 6</a></li>
  <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 7</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I would like the menu text centered vertically within the container, but they are hugging the top. How would I do this?

---

I worked on this last night and this is what I came up with:

My goal using Bootstrap, was to have a series of menu links running horizontally across the page. For some reason, doubtless due to my ignorance, this proved rather difficult. I did come up with a solution. At least this seems to work, OK. HOWEVER, in order to make the horizontal menu items appear vertically centered within the container, I had to add margin-top: 3px to the class view. This feels kind of fake to me, but whatever works works, I guess. Any comments are appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TEST</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>

<style>
.view {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-top: 3px;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="Jumbotron">
           <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Using Bookstreap.js</h1>
           <hr>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default view ">
             <div class="container-fluid view">
           <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-10 view" >
             <ul class="list-inline view"  >
               <li class="view"><a href="/">Menu 1</a></li>
               <li class="view"><a href="/Menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
               <li class="view"><a href="/Menu1">Menu 2</a></li></li>
               <li class="view"><a href="/Menu1">Menu 3</a></li>
               <li class="view"><a href="/Menu1">Menu 4</a></li>
               <li class="view"><a href="/Menu1">Menu 5</a></li>
               <li class="view"><a href="/Menu1">Menu 6</a></li>
             </ul>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </nav>
  <div>
```

Comment: Do you want the Text to be vertically centered in the nav? or Nav vertically centered in the container?

Comment: I would like the text vertically centered within the nav.

Comment: If you're just trying to vertically center your links change your `ul` from `list-inline vcenter` to the default classes `nav navbar-nav`. See [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
{ 
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 float:none;



}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default vcenter "  >
      <div class="container-fluid vcenter">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-5" >
    <ul class="list-inline vcenter" >

    <div>

   <li class="menuFont"><a href="/">Menu 1</a></li>
   <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 2</a></li>
   <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 3</a></li>
   <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 4</a></li>
   <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 5</a></li>
   <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 6</a></li>
  <li class="menuFont "><a href="/Menu 2">Menu 7</a></li>
  <div>
  </ul>
  </div>


</div>
</nav>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See my comment above (I want the menu items vertically centered within the nav) BUT another comment: I thought from the Bootstrap.css comments that the two types of containers could not be nested. Am I not understanding that correctly?

Comment: they can be nested in your case.

Comment: when I added the div after the ul, I got all the li's stacked vertically I want them horizontal but centered within the div container.